# How to help java tomcat processes to regain used memory?

Tags: java, memory, tomcat, memory-management

We are running an web application that is using Java 64bit 5 gigs of -Xmx of maximum heap size.  We have no control over the java code.  We can only tweak configuration parameters.  The situation that we are facing is that the java processes after it takes the full heap allocated at start up, it starts acting very responding very slow to web site requests.  My guess is that is waiting for the GC to collect unused memory objects.

The image below will show you a image of top in linux that shows the critical situation of the processes.

[top image of java process http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/java-gc-issue.jpg](http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/java-gc-issue.jpg)

Is there any way, we can help java regain the used memory inside the allocated space.

EDIT 1:
I used some of the answers below to be able to get to the answer of my question. Since my question was too difficult to answer, and it turned out to be a discussion.  I will post how I was able to monitor the GC cycles and I will pick the answer with more votes.  I used jconsole through real vnc viewer to be able to hook from my windows machine to my linux machine running tomcat.

I used this parameters to start the java processes:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms512m -Xmx5120m -Dbuild.compiler.emacs=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

This is the type of output I got, from jconsole through vnc viewer.
[GC Sample Image http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/Sample_GC_Image.jpg](http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/Sample_GC_Image.jpg)

Comment: This isn't really proramming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend that you not guess.  Get some data to see exactly what's going on.  You can use [visual gc](http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/visualgc.html) to see what's happening.

If it's the perm space that's being filled up, there won't be much you can do.

Which JVM?  If it's 5 or higher there are additional parameters besides just max heap size you can adjust.  Check out http://blog.springsource.com/2008/10/14/optimising-and-tuning-apache-tomcat-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a memory leak if your application is getting progressively slower. The GC will always start to clean up unused objects as soon as it needs to. If you add -verbosegc you will be able to see how often a GC is performed and much memory is free after a GC. If the heap is more than 80% used you either have to increase the max memory or fix the program so it doesn't use so much.

Can you do a `numactl --hardware` ? I suggest you not use more than 80% of one memory bank or your GC times will increases dramatically.

Comment: "not use more than 80% of one memory bank", sounds interesting. Do you have references or benchmarks for this statement?

Comment: Good question.  This is mostly observation and technical anecdote from RedHat specialists. I have found memory architecture makes a significant difference to latency but I haven't done measurements for throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to get details of what's using up the stack. For that I recommend JMAP (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jmap.html) which you can run on the process ID (PID) to see what's using memory. Take JMAP snapshots several times when the application is running and see what classes are not freeing up the stack.

Cheers,

-Richard

Answer (score 1):

Try running the app with the  `-verbose:gc -Xloggc:/path/to/where/you/want/gc.log` parameters, and study the resulting gc.log; it should tell you how much time is being spent in garbage collection. Or, as Duffymo suggests above, use visualGC to give you the same data.

Make sure you're using an appropriate colllector - you probably want either the parallel or low-pause (CMS) collectors, assuming you're on java 5.

Have a read of [Sun's GC tuning document](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html) to see what else you can tweak. On occasions I have found very large heaps to be counter-productive (assuming the application doesn't actually *need* all that space); more frequent, smaller collections can sometimes end up less disruptive than occasional massive ones.